# Is there a better way to concatenate variables in a string with no spaces?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have this (simplified) code:

```
$hostname = "127.0.0.1"
$aaa= "http://$hostname:8001"
Write-Host $aaa
```

Output is

> http://

The problem is the colon following the $hostname variable, so I fixed it this way:

```
$hostname = "127.0.0.1"
$aaa= "http://$hostname" + ":8001"
Write-Host $aaa
```

I was wondering if **is there any better way of doing it using any PowerShell technology I am not aware of**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two way:

```
"http://$($hostname):8001"
```

or

```
"http://$hostname`:8001"
```

The colon is reserved in variable names: it associate the variable with a specific scope or namespace:

```
$global:var
```

or

```
$env:PATH
```

The part before the ':' can be a scope  or a PSDrive.

Comment: I knew it (the first one)... but I forgot it! Thanks :). The second one I was not aware...

Comment: @EBGreen Isn't just for fun, is a good way, `-f` can save your life in many situation!

Comment: In general it is my default method for string building.

Comment: @EBGreen I abuse of it in c# but I forgot it everytime in powershell! That's why your comment is really welcome ;)

Comment: Ya, it has been brought down from C which is where I started using it.